# Implementation for a method that finds the first nonrepeatable character in a string using Linq, while crossing through the string only once

Tags: c#, linq

I have to implement a method that finds the first character from a string that does not repeat itself, while using Linq methods and not going through the string more than once. This is what i have so far, and, while it does use Linq methods, it crosses the string several times. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

```
public class StringUsingLinq
{
    string givenString;

    public char GiveTheFirstCharThatDoesntRepeat()
    {
        Func<char, bool> noRepeat= x => givenString.IndexOf(x) == givenString.LastIndexOf(x);
        return givenString.First(noRepeat);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some example input values and expected results (plural) for each example? Also, how should numbers be handled?

Comment: For example, you have the string "Ana are mere", so the result should be "r" because it's the first character that doesn't repeat.

Comment: I would think that "n" should be the correct answer because it is the first that does not repeat. In fact, "n" and "m" are the only letters that do not repeat."r" does repeat. 
—> According to your example “For example, you have the string "Ana are mere", so the result should be "r" because it's the first character that doesn't repeat.”

Answer (score 4):

```
public char? GiveTheFirstCharThatDoesntRepeat(string givenString)
{
    return givenString
        .GroupBy(c => c)
        .FirstOrDefault(grp => grp.Count() == 1)?
        .Key;
}
```

Note that `char?` should be used, because it is possible that the `givenString` may only have repeating characters.

Comment: Thank you so much this is perfect

Comment: You need to do `?.Key` to return the char instead of `IGrouping<char, char>`